# Facing error while using Pafy library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I'm using Pafy Library in Python few days ago my code is working fine but now when I run my code I'm facing this error** 
*I'm using Kali Linux and running this code in Terminal *

**Here is my code**

```
import pafy
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2tEPmwWEiI"
video=pafy.new(url)
print(video.title)
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: y2tEPmwWEiI: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shiva/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 796, in extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "/home/shiva/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 530, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "/home/shiva/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 1839, in _real_extract
    raise ExtractorError(
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: y2tEPmwWEiI: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shiva/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 40, in _fetch_basic
    self._ydl_info = ydl.extract_info(self.videoid, download=False)
  File "/home/shiva/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 819, in extract_info
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "/home/shiva/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 624, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "/home/shiva/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 594, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: y2tEPmwWEiI: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data
```

Comment: Try updating ```pafy```

Comment: But I didn't find anything in Pafy documentation! How will you please help me?

Comment: first check if you have the newest version of `Pafy` and `youtube_dl`. Few weeks ago there was problem with other module for `YouTube` because `YouTube` changed code on server and it needed changes in module - and installing the newest version could help. Or you may need to wait for newer version.

Comment: didn't get any update news in Pafy documentation.

Comment: documentation may need also updates - and it needs time and someone to do it - so don't check documentation but try `pip install --update`.

Comment: you could also check [pafy repo on Github](https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy) - there is info when there was last change in code. And you can check [issues](https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/issues) to see if someone else had the same problem in few last days. Beacause error shows `backend_youtube_dl.py` so I would check also repo and issues for [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl)

Comment: sure bro !! if you find any solution ping me, please. Let me also try to find something.